# Is it possible to determine the type of a class field based on the value assigned to it within the function of the class itself?

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, c++20, coroutine

Is it possible to determine the type of a class field based on the value assigned to it within the function of the class itself?

I am writing a wrapper for the ozo library which is based on the boost.Asio library in order to use it with c ++ 20 coroutines. Such a strange need arose in the inability to set the type of the conn field, which must be returned.

The type I need is deduced when the operator () is called on the object `ozo :: request_op <Initiator> reqOp;`.A callback is passed to operator (), where the second argument is a variable of the type I need. The type defined for the second argument of the callback must be defined for the class field Awaiter conn.

In this case, I determined the conn type ConnectionPtr, but this is wrong, because it is suitable only for one specific case. I need to make this functor more versatile. There is also an option how to pass conn from await_suspend to await_resume, but as far as I know, this can only be done through the awaiter class.

```
 using ConnectionPtr = std::shared_ptr<ozo::pooled_connection<
            yamail::resource_pool::handle<ozo::connection_rep<ozo::oid_map_t<>,
                    ozo::none_t>>, boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>>;

    template<typename Initiator>
    class RequestOp {
    private:
        ozo::request_op<Initiator> reqOp;
    private:

        template<typename P, typename Q, typename TimeConstraint, typename Out>
        struct Awaiter {
            const RequestOp<Initiator> &reqOp;
            P &&provider;
            Q &&query;
            TimeConstraint t;
            Out out;

            ozo::error_code ec;
            ConnectionPtr conn;

            bool await_ready() {
                return false;
            }

            void await_suspend(std::coroutine_handle<> coro) {
                reqOp.reqOp(std::move(provider), std::move(query), t, out, [this, coro](ozo::error_code ec,
                                                                                        auto conn) mutable {
                    this->ec = ec;
                    this->conn = conn;
                    coro.resume();
                });

            }

            decltype(auto) await_resume() {
                return std::pair<ConnectionPtr, ozo::error_code>{conn, ec};
            }
        };

    public:
        template<typename P, typename Q, typename TimeConstraint, typename Out>
        decltype(auto) operator()(P &&provider, Q &&query, TimeConstraint t, Out out) const {
            return Awaiter<P, Q, TimeConstraint, Out>{*this, std::forward<P>(provider), std::forward<Q>(query), t, out};
        }
    };

    constexpr RequestOp<ozo::detail::initiate_async_request> Request;
```

I understand that all types in c ++ are defined at compile time. The type passed to the callback is also determined at compile time. The problem is that I don't know how to tell the compiler what type to determine for the conn field. Although at compile time, the type I need is already known, it is defined for the second argument of the callback function passed to operator () request

The end goal is to pass conn to await_resume and return from it, but unfortunately
await_resume takes no arguments and this must be done through the awaiter class. Maybe there are other ways?

Comment: Side note: `decltype(auto)` usually is not necessary, pure `auto` is just as fine. `decltype(auto)` is one of the view cases where parentheses around return values are relevant and can produce dangling references.

Comment: The "the type of a class field" is ***always*** determined at compile time, and you should already know it. There's never any mystery about it, at runtime. That's the only way C++ works. If you still think you need to "determine" the type of some field, you need to provide additional information as to what's unclear to you, or rephrase your question, because at stated the answer would be "you already know it, otherwise your C++ program will not compile".

Comment: I understand that all types in c ++ are defined at compile time. The type passed to the callback is also determined at compile time. The problem is that I don't know how to tell the compiler what type to determine for the conn field. Although at compile time, the type I need is already known, it is defined for the second argument of the callback function passed to operator () request. @SamVarshavchik

Comment: The type of "the second argument of the callback function" appears to be `Q`. That's what it is declared to be. If the parameter to the callback function is itself a function, and you want to know the type of its argument, then this is a simple task for a specialization helper, but you should be able to explain this issue in a much simpler way, using a much simpler example, without involving a speciality third-party library, but using just standard, native C++ types.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, Not the second argument of the () operator, the second argument of the callback function passed to this operator.

Comment: [this, coro](ozo::error_code ec, auto conn) mutable{...} 
Need a type assigned instead of auto to conn
@SamVarshavchik

Comment: `decltype(conn)` would give it to you. Perhaps a `std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(conn)>`.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I don't understand how to apply this to my situation, could you please frame an example?

Comment: `decltype(conn)` is really all there is to it. This gives you `conn`'s type. See your C++ textbook for more information on how to use `decltype`.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can’t do this because the type of the parameter `conn` is determined **elsewhere**, by code that might in some cases be declared after this class is defined.  If the function accepting the callback returns something whose **type** is based on the type the callback returns, you can write something like `decltype(reqOp.reqOp(…,[](auto x) {return x;}))`, but otherwise the information about what type was passed is lost.  (There are stateful metaprogramming tricks that might be used to exfiltrate the information with a similar trick, but they’re best avoided.)